# Center Text Below Image in Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I built an HTML table and centered the images within it (TABLE 1 example).
The image will be a link, but the text will not be a link.
I need some help centering text/headline that is in the same "td" tag as an image.

I included code for TABLE 2, but this is just an example of another table that has the CONTENT perfectly centered below the image you see in TABLE 1. I do not want two tables because the text is too far below the image. I need the text to be closer to the image above it.

I only want one table...TABLE 1. And I need some help adding content/text/headline directly below each image. I added a p tag in the first td of TABLE 1, but that is not working.

I have tried looking at other table and css examples, but I have not had good results yet.
Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

I have tried adding different CSS styles including margin, padding, text align center, and so on...
So far I not been able to successfully center the text right below the image.

This image is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

TABLE 1 (examples of images that are correctly centered)

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#"><img style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;" src="https://www.website.com/images/image1.png" /></a>
        <p style="font- 
    size:24px;">CONTENT</p>
      </td>

      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#"><img style="width:70%; float: left; margin: 25px;" src="https://www.website.com/images/image2.png" /></a>
      </td>

      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#"><img style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;" src="https://www.website.com/images/image3.png" /></a>
      </td>

      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#"><img style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;" src="https://www.website.com/images/image4.png" /></a>
      </td>

      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#"><img style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;" src="https://www.website.com/images/image5.png" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

TABLE 2 (examples of centering CONTENT...this content is centered perfectly below the images, but I do not want two tables due to vertical spacing is too much)

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr style="font-size:24px;">
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;">CONTENT 1</span>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;">CONTENT 2</span>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;">CONTENT 3</span>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;">CONTENT 4</span>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="width: 70%; float: left; margin: 25px;">CONTENT 5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are the images `float:left` if you want them centered? Also, the `margin 25px` on the images seems to be pushing them to the right of the cell. Remove the margin and the float and they're automatically centered due to the `text-align: center`. You can control the space around the image with `padding:25px` in the table cell.

Comment: So what is the exact issue that you are trying to resolve? Table 1 does seem to have image as link and a text centered below it.

Comment: float:left and margin: 25px were both used to help tighten up the space between each image/text td element.
I needed those elements closer together.

I am able to get the headline centered below the image, but is one of the headlines has too many characters, then that td section is not in line with the other td elements.

Comment: Using two tables (table 1 for images and table 2 for content/headline) helps prevent any issues if a headline has too many characters and a td element is no longer horizontally in line with the other td elements, but then I have trouble with vertical spacing (the headline is too far below each image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be centered fine when I load your code, except the `float:left` on the image can throw it off (see [my example](https://scriptbarrel.com/ex2.htm). The image on the right is floated left and doesn't look as centered).

If you want the text under the image anyway, there's no need for `float:left` because that makes the image sit to the left of any elements after it. Depending on image size, the paragraph with the **CONTENT** text will move next to the image instead of below it.

Really it would be best to use an external stylesheet, all your inline code is hard to keep track of. Also, the `margin:25px` on the image will enlarge or shrink the image depending on the margin size: The margin expands or shrinks the table cell, and the 70% fixed width makes the image move with the size of the cell to keep the margin the same.

Don't forget you have `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes to adjust the width between table cells, and the space around items in the cells: `<table cellspacing="15">` will put 15 pixels cushion between cells.

**Update:** For the problems with longer captions pushing the image up, an easy solution is to put all the captions in their own table row. This still only uses one table, and the distance between the captions and the images can be adjusted with negative CSS margins. [Example here](https://scriptbarrel.com/ex2.htm).

Comment: This is a good solution to the issue I was trying to figure out. Thank you for your help!.

Comment: Glad it helped. Also if you ever want to adjust the other margins inside the cells, you can use `margin: -10px 25px 25px 25px` for example to raise it up 10px but have all the other margins stay 25px. The margins in CSS are ordered **top, right, bottom, left** (clockwise)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is a figure element and the text / link in a figcaption. The figcaption can be the first child or last child in the figure element (effectively meaning it can be placed before or after the image.

```css
figure a img {
 width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
       <figure>
         <a href="#">
           <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
         </a>
         <figcaption>Content</figcaption>
       </figure>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
       <figure>
         <a href="#">
           <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
         </a>
         <figcaption>Content</figcaption>
       </figure>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
       <figure>
         <a href="#">
           <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
         </a>
         <figcaption>Content</figcaption>
       </figure>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This updated code using the p tag for the headline works with centering the headline under the image, but if a headline has too many characters you can see that td element does not align with the other td elements.

[long character example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHhQB.jpg)

```
<div>
<table>
<tbody><tr>

<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><img style="width: 70%;/* float: left; *//* margin: 25px; */" src="https://www.website.com/images/image1.png" /></a>
<p style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold;">HEADLINE</p> 
</td>

<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><img style="width:70%;/* float: left; *//* margin: 25px; */" src="https://www.website.com/images/image2.png" /></a>
<p style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold;">LONG HEADLINE</p> 
</td>

<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><img style="width: 70%;/* float: left; *//* margin: 25px; */" src="https://www.website.com/images/image3.png" /></a>
<p style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold;">HEADLINE</p> 
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><img style="width: 70%;/* float: left; *//* margin: 25px; */" src="https://www.website.com/images/image4.png" /></a>
<p style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold;">HEADLINE</p> 
</td>

<td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><img style="width: 70%;/* float: left; *//* margin: 25px; */" src="https://www.website.com/images/image5.png" /></a>
<p style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold;">HEADLINE</p> 
</td>

</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my answer and example to show how it works a lot easier with a second table row `<tr>` for the captions. CSS can adjust all the spacing however you want. You might not even need the `float:left` hack this way, which could cause problems later down the road.